# Scala: Eliminating getters and setters when using java frameworks that require them... (Java/Scala interoperability)

Tags: scala, properties, functional-programming, pojo

Hey I'm using getters and setters because I'm relying on java libraries that don't have scala versions yet (tinkerpop but it's not relevant).

Is there any way to rewrite my code to eliminate the mutability when using java frameworks?

```
trait GraphedUser extends BaseFramedEntity{

    @Property(GraphedUser.USER_USERID)
    def setUserId (userId: String)

    @Property(GraphedUser.USER_USERID)
    def getUserId:String

    @Property("firstName")
    def setFirstName (userId: String)

    @Property("firstName")
    def getFirstName:String

    // ...
}
```

Comment: What part of the Tinkerpop stack? There's a Scala port for Gremlin.

Comment: Mutability/Immutability is a fundamental design decision when creating/using an API. There is no "magical switch" between the two. (This is why it's often nicer to deal with a Scala port/wrapper than the original Java library - the former will support a more "functional/Scala style".)

Comment: Frames in particular. I guess I could write a wrapper.